# PhpStorm remote development access to remote http with browser

Tags: docker, phpstorm, remote-access

I setup remove development with PhpStorm - works fine. But how can I connect to the website provided with remote machine?

Is it possible to make some proxy / tunnel or something ?

On the remote host I have docker containers that provide hosts like `http://myapp.demo`.

i see in /etc/hosts on remote i have
172.25.0.3 myapp.demo
so its local subnetwork for remote.
When i create proxy its not accessible for local.

Also i try ssh connection with -X forward and try run browser example firefox but get

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Error: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
```

So remote desktop like vnc only way ?

Answer (score 0):

Since 2022.3, you can forward ports in Backend Status Details:

[image]